# Formatting as Phone Number on Custom UITextField while typing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, phone-number, nsformatter

I have custom UITextFields that I created using [TextFieldEffects](https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects). Now I have a different challenge that I need to use phone number formatting for some instances of TextFieldEffects but not all. At this point, I've found [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit), which seems to be doing exactly what I want to do.

However, TextFieldEffects is an instance of UITextField [that can be seen here](https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects/blob/master/TextFieldEffects/TextFieldEffects/TextFieldsEffects.swift), thus if I change `UITextField` to `PhoneNumberTextField` on line 23, it will affect all of the TextFieldEffects.

Is there a way I can combine these two libraries and be able to get some fields to be affected by PhoneNumberKit but not all?

---

Or is there any better / more convenient way *(maybe any other library or without using external library)* to achieve what I want to achieve? What other options do I have? What is the best approach on this case?

---

For further discussion, I asked another question [here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36042018/formatting-uitextfields-text-as-phone-number-as-user-types-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you look through the documentation and delegate methods of both of your libraries, you should be able to integrate the two. Without doing all the work, you should use `UITextFieldDelegate` to tell you when text has changed, and then use the formatter methods of `PhoneNumberKit` to take that raw string and update the contents of your custom TextField.

Comment: Can you please write a mini-guide for that if you have time? I am very confused on what to do next. I'd be very greatful

Comment: I tried achieving it with `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` but I couldn't make it work. Can you please check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026247/uitextfield-shouldchangecharactersinrange-doesnt-detect-first-character)