# Formatting UITextField's text as Phone Number as user types in

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, phone-number, nsformatter

I have a custom UITextField, which I am trying to 'format the input to phone number' as user types. What I want to achieve:

- Adding a prefixed `+` sign on the UITextField as the first character, that cannot be deleted.
- Format both the String variable and UITextField's text in the format of phone number nicely *(+49 291 12345678)*, rather than plain numbers *(4929112345678)* as user types in.

---

I researched and found out that there is no built-in method for that. I've also found easy-to-use library called [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit) for formatting the input String to Phone number. In Playground, it works like..

```
let rawNumberArray = "+4929112345678"
let phoneNumbers = PartialFormatter().formatPartial(rawNumberArray)

print(phoneNumbers) // "+49 291 12345678"
```

Bare in mind that, the library needs the String to have `+` as the first character to format properly.

---

I tried implementing it on my UITextField.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    if textField == myTextField {
        let candidateString : NSString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        let updatedTextString : NSString = PartialFormatter().formatPartial(candidateString as String)

        self.formattedPhoneNumber(updatedTextString, textField: textField)
    }
    return true
}

func formattedPhoneNumber(updatedTextString: NSString, textField: UITextField) {
    //  textField.text = "+\(updatedTextString as String)"
    print(updatedTextString)
}
```

If I keep `textField.text = "+\(updatedTextString as String)"` commented, `print(updatedTextString)` prints nicely formatted String on the console, BUT inside UITextField on UI, it just shows plain, unstructured numbers like "4929112345678"

If I uncomment it, things start to get weird and UITextField starts present duplicated characters in the UI, but console log for print also gets pretty weird. I also tried emptying `textField.text =  ""` before, but didn't work either.

---

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing that doesn't let it work fine? I believe it's related with me and not the library itself.

Also, if you have any other suggestions (or libraries) for me to overcome this problem, please share them.

Comment: If you update the text field's `text` via the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` function, you must return `false` from `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

Comment: I tried changing the `return true` to `return false`. Having `textField.text = "+\(updatedTextString as String)"` unfortunately adds `+` sign each time I click on 'Delete'. There is a logic mistake in my approach but I couldn't figure it out. I'd be grateful, if you can add an answer so I can try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing the values you want to show, should return `false` after replacing the text. Here is an example:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let text = textField.text {
        print("curText: \(text) range: \(range.location)-\(range.length) string: \(string)" )

        let candidate = (text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        if(!candidate.isCorrectFormat()){
            textField.text = callYourFormatMethodHere();

            return false
        }

    }

    return true
}
```

You need to implement your own isCorrectFormat() and callYourFormatMethodHere().

Edit:

Use your code:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    if textField == myTextField {
        let candidateString : NSString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        let updatedTextString : NSString = PartialFormatter().formatPartial(candidateString as String)

        self.formattedPhoneNumber(updatedTextString, textField: textField)

        return false // Return false here
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I couldn't fully understand how to use it with `PartialFormatter().formatPartial(candidateString as String)`. What does it actually do? I want to add a prefixed `'+' sign` in the beginning that can't be deleted; and format the text as phone number format (using the PhoneNumberKit looked convenient to me)

Comment: See the updated, you need to replace the isCorrectFormat() and callYourFormatMethodHere() to yours.

Comment: I couldn't fully understand your approach and also got confused implementing it to test what it does as candidate.isCorrectFormat() doesn't let me do it. But from the print line, I can say it's for detecting the + sign and for preventing it to get deleted; am I right or completely out of track? So what I need to do is detecting if the pressed button is a number (not a + sign), and act accordingly like append to textField. Is that right?

Comment: I don't know why you don't understand, I thought it's quite clear, see the edited.

Comment: In reality, the UX should be more complicate.  You don't want to only do the conversion when the user has done typing.  You want to keep checking format while use is typing.  e.g. Add a "+" is user didn't type "+", or only allow Numbers.  That's why I said you need to implement your own isCorrectFormat.

Comment: Ahh I understand now. But still I couldn't make it work. In my `formattedPhoneNumber` method, if I have only `textField.text = "+\(updatedTextString as String)"` and `print()`, for example if I type 6 characters and try to delete all, it will be +++++ after a point. It's quite weird on that point. Is my problem in my formattedPhoneNumber() method, `textField.text = "+\(updatedTextString as String)"`? What should I have inside that function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106501/discussion-between-senty-and-dichen).